# ReactJs implement function saveAll from backend

Tags: java, reactjs, forms, axios, save

How to create this functionality using Axios? I'd like to save many entities at once a request, you can see it on the picture:

[image: screenshot]

Maybe it's possible to add the new form on the fly and create one submit button for all forms.

More code here:

[image]

It's simple to save one entity:

```js
save = async(employee) => {
  if (employee.id) {
    return axios.put(this.baseURL + "/" + `${employee.id}`, employee).then(res => res.data);
  } else {
    return axios.post(this.baseURL + "/", employee).then(res => res.data);
  }
};
```

and Form:

```html
<form id="employee-form" onSubmit={this.employeeService}>
  <span className="p-float-label">
  <InputText style={{width : '100%'}} hidden={true} value={this.state.selectedEmployee.id} onChange={(e) => {
  let val = e.target.value;
  this.setState(prevState => {
    let employee = Object.assign({}, prevState.employee);
    employee.id = val;

    return {
      employee
    };
  })
}} />
</span>
```

and backend service:

```
public List<Employee> saveListEmployees(Iterable<Employee> employeeListDto) {
   return employeeRepository.saveAll(employeeListDto);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can juste post in Array of items like params in request

```
const employees = [{...},{...},{...}]       
return axios.post(this.baseURL + "/addAll", employees ).then(res => res.data)
```

In your back-end create a controller accept List like parametre, and continue the road to databas ...

I hope it will be useful for you, and good luck